# How to get passed attributes from custom directive and collect them in an array to show into template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

I have created a custom directive which should display a slider with the data entered to the custom directive. I need to be able to display the image Url and redirect Link via directive attributes for example:

```
<div class="sliderBanner" imgUrl="http://example.com/img1.jpg" imgLink="example.com"></div>
<div class="sliderBanner" imgUrl="http://example.com/img2.jpg" imgLink="example.com"></div>
<div class="sliderBanner" imgUrl="http://example.com/img3.jpg" imgLink="example.com"></div>
```

Now I want to collect those data and place them inside an array within directive scope and use ng-repeat inside directive template to show them.
e
PS: I'm using Swiper angular directive for slider purpose.

```
var app = angular.module('APP',['ksSwiper']);

app.directive('sliderBanner',function($http){
    return{
        scope:true,
        restrict:'C',  
        link: function(scope,element,attr){
            scope.data = [];
            scope.data.push({
                "id": attr.id,
                "imgUrl": attr.imgUrl,
                "imgRef": attr.imgRef
             });
        },
        templateUrl: 'http://www.lajmislam.com/wp-content/themes/Newspaper/ng-templates/sliderBanner.html'    
    }
});
```

This is my directive template:

```
<ks-swiper-container autoplay="3000" show-nav-buttons="true"  pagination-is-active="true" swiper="swiper">
           <ks-swiper-slide ng-repeat="item in data">
              {{item.id}},{{item.imgUrl}}
          </ks-swiper-slide>
    </ks-swiper-container>

    <div ng-repeat="item in data">
        {{item.id}},{{item.imgUrl}}
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What errors are you seeing?

What you have here appears to be working. I tested it out here: https://github.com/styonsk/StackOverflowSolutions/tree/master/35997232

Comment: I don't have errors but the display isn't correct you can check it here lajmislam.com at the right sidebar below the advertisement banner. From your example I saw you called the data array from the controller, I meant can I create those data from the directive tag atttributes as per the first code at my question